# descarga de imagenen que esta en la DB

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, mysqli

como hago para descargar y que se muestre en pantalla una imagen previamente cargada a la base de datos

este es el php que busca cargar la imagen lo hago con la variable pero lo unico que carga es el nombre de la imagen

```
                        <?php
                             include('is_logged.php');//Archivo verifica que 
                    el usario que intenta acceder a la URL esta logueado
                  /* Connect To Database*/
           require_once ("../config/db.php");//Contiene las variables de 
           configuracion para conectar a la base de datos
            require_once ("../config/conexion.php");//Contiene funcion que 
              conecta a la base de datos
         $action = (isset($_REQUEST['action'])&& $_REQUEST['action'] 
        !=NULL)?$_REQUEST['action']:'';
          if (isset($_GET['Nticket'])){
        $incidencia=intval($_GET['Nticket']);
          $query=mysqli_query($con, "select * from ticket where 
         Nticket='".$Nticket."'");
             $rw_user=mysqli_fetch_array($query);
             $count=$rw_ticket['Nticket'];
          if ($Nticket!=1){
    if ($delete1=mysqli_query($con,"DELETE FROM ticket WHERE Nticket='".$Nticket."'")){
    ?>
    <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
      <strong>Aviso!</strong> Datos eliminados exitosamente.
    </div>
    <?php 
}else {
    ?>
    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
      <strong>Error!</strong> Lo siento algo ha salido mal intenta nuevamente.
    </div>
    <?php

}

} else {
    ?>
    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
      <strong>Error!</strong> No se pudo eliminar ésta  categoría. Existen productos vinculados a ésta categoría. 
    </div>
    <?php
}



           }
            if($action == 'ajax'){
            // escaping, additionally removing everything that could be 
       (html/javascript-) code
  $q = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_REQUEST['q'], 
        ENT_QUOTES)));
 $aColumns = array('Nticket');//Columnas de busqueda
 $sTable = "ticket";
 $sWhere = "";
if ( $_GET['q'] != "" )
{
    $sWhere = "WHERE (";
    for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
    {
        $sWhere .= $aColumns[$i]." LIKE '%".$q."%' OR ";
    }
    $sWhere = substr_replace( $sWhere, "", -3 );
    $sWhere .= ')';
}
$sWhere.=" order by Nticket";
include 'pagination.php'; //include pagination file
//pagination variables
$page = (isset($_REQUEST['page']) && !empty($_REQUEST['page']))?$_REQUEST['page']:1;
$per_page = 10; //how much records you want to show
$adjacents  = 4; //gap between pages after number of adjacents
$offset = ($page - 1) * $per_page;
//Count the total number of row in your table*/
$count_query   = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT count(*) AS numrows FROM $sTable  $sWhere");
$row= mysqli_fetch_array($count_query);
$numrows = $row['numrows'];
$total_pages = ceil($numrows/$per_page);
$reload = './clientes.php';
//main query to fetch the data
$sql="SELECT * FROM  $sTable $sWhere LIMIT $offset,$per_page";
$query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
//loop through fetched data
if ($numrows>0){
    ?>
<div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table">
        <tr  class="danger">
            <th>ticket</th>
            <th>Incidencia</th>
            <th>Tema</th>
            <th>Detalle</th>
        </tr>
            <?php
    $nums=0;
        while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
                $Nticket=$row['Nticket'];
                $incidencia=$row['incidencia'];
                $tema=$row['tema'];
                $detalle=$row['detalle'];
                 $_FILES['imagen']['name']=$row['imagen'];

                $nums++;



                ?>


            <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['Nticket'];?>" id="Nticket<?php echo $Nticket;?>">
            <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['incidencia'];?>" id="incidencia<?php echo $incidencia;?>">
            <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['tema'];?>" id="tema<?php echo $tema;?>">
            <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['detalle'];?>" id="detalle<?php echo $detalle;?>">
            <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['imagen'];?>" id="imagen<?php echo $_FILES['imagen']['name'];?>">
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $Nticket; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $incidencia; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $tema; ?></td>
                <td><a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal_<?php echo $nums; ?>"><li 
               class='glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign'></li></a>
            <div class="modal fade" id="myModal_<?php echo $nums; ?>" role="dialog">
       <div class="modal-dialog">
       <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
   <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;
          </button>
       <h4 class="modal-title">Detalle de la incidencia</h4>
   </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
    <p><?php echo $detalle;?></p>
    <p><?php echo $_FILES['imagen']['name'];?></p>
 </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
  </div>
  </div>

      </div>
 </div>
```

prueba

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola nuevamente jejeje esto pasa por que en ningún momento estas "copiando" la imagen a un directorio de tu sitio, únicamente estas guardando el nombre en la base de datos.

Para copiar la imagen debes hacer lo siguiente en el php en el cual insertas los datos a la tabla:

```
$imagen = $_FILES['imagen']['name']; //Esta variable ya la estás capturando
$ruta_tmp = $_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'];

$ruta_final = '../img/' . $imagen; //Debes tener mucho cuidado con la forma en que haces la ruta del directorio, si la copias mal no se moverá correctamente la imagen

if (!file_exists($ruta_final)) {
    move_uploaded_file($ruta_tmp, $ruta_final);
}
```

Después de esto puedes verificar que la imagen se haya copiado en el directorio que colocaste en la variable `$ruta_final` y la llamas desde el `html` con una etiqueta `img` así:

```
<img src="img/<?php echo $_FILES['imagen']['name']; ?>">
```

Espero que te sirva, saludos !

Comment: una pregunta en el  $ruta_tmp = $_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name']; el ['tmp_name']; si esta bien? porque me da error

Comment: Claro, cuando tu subes una imagen por medio de un formulario el servidor la guarda en una ruta temporal, el ['tmp_name'] captura esa ruta temporal y luego se le dice que mueva la imagen desde la ruta temporal hasta la ruta propia del directorio de tu sitio

Comment: mira Notice: Undefined index: tmp_name in C:\wamp64\www\Nueva carpeta\ajax\buscar_ticket.php on line 94

Comment: pa ya me tengo que ir pero te agradezco la ayuda mañana tempreno vuelvo XD gracias

Comment: Mira bien si lo estás colocando en el archivo dónde haces el registro a la base de datos, si el sistema te captura el ['name'] también te debería capturar el ['tmp_name'], también puedes sacar un var_dump(); de $_FILES['imagen'] para ver el array completo a ver qué te está arrojando ! Me avisas el resultado de estas pruebas que te acabo de decir

Comment: mi intencion es colocarlo junto al detalle en el modal que hice ayer pero coloco las variables hay mismo o donde hago el registro

Comment: La parte donde mueves el archivo de la carpeta temporal a la carpeta de tu site la debes hacer después de que guardas en la base de datos el nombre de dicho archivo, después de que verifiques que el archivo se movió correctamente puedes acceder a el desde cualquier parte con la etiqueta <img>

Comment: osea seria despues del insert?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66398/discussion-between-camilo-vasquez-and-kevin-salazar).

Comment: no es necesario ya lo hice muchas gracias por la ayuda ya me inserta la imagen que pongo una cosilla muy rapida podria cambiar la carpeta de destino lo que pasa es que aveces me entra en conflicto con una que tengo ya creada

Comment: Si claro, en `$ruta_final` puedes colocar la ruta que quieras y desde esa misma ruta accedes a la imagen